# ¿como puedo conservar los valores flotantes de mi archivo de entrada e imprimirlos en un archivo de salida sin afectar los numeros despues del punto?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
FILE *datos;
datos= fopen("DATOS.txt", "r");
FILE *ganancia;
ganancia= fopen("GANANCIA.txt", "r");
FILE *resultados;
resultados= fopen("RESULTADOS.txt","w");

int i, n, anio[40];
int fil, col;
float ventas[40][12];
fscanf(datos,"%d", &n);
fprintf(resultados, "AÑO                                                                                           MES\n                    ENE              FEB            MAR            ABR           MAY          JUN              JUL            AGO          SEP           OCT          NOV            DIC  \n");
//creacion de columna de años
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    fscanf(datos,"%d", &anio[i]);
    fprintf(resultados, "%d \n", anio[i]);
}

fscanf (ganancia,"%f %f", &fil, &col);
/*creacion de la matriz que tiene los valores flotantes, las filas son 28 y las columnas 12
guarda los valores correctos antes del punto, esta limitado para 2 decimales, pero solo
guarda 00 o 50 despues del punto siendo valores diferentes a los de la entrada del archivo*/
for (i=0; i<28; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<12; j++){
        fscanf(ganancia,"%f", &ventas[i][j]);
        printf("%.2f\t ", ventas [i][j]);
        fprintf(resultados, "%.2f\t", ventas [i][j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
    fprintf(resultados, "\n");

}
fclose(datos);
fclose(ganancia);
fclose(resultados);
system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo de entrada 5000345.70 Ejemplo de impresion en otro archivo
5000345.50 Cambia los valores despues del punto, tambien quisiera ayuda para imprimirlo en forma de lista, que la matriz donde estan todas las ganancias, este a lado de la columna donde estan los años.

Comment: puedes colocar un poco mas de tu codigo, porque con ese ciclo no puedo deducir el problema, segun el ciclo esta bien pero mucho depende del tipo de guardado que estes haciendo y los tipo de datos que usas al recuperar y guardar en el archivo

Comment: Acabo de agregar el codigo completo

Answer (score 1):

Según [wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formato_en_coma_flotante_de_simple_precisi%C3%B3n), el `float` de 32 bits proporciona una precisión de 6 a 9 dígitos decimales significativos.

El problema no está en tu código, el número que quieres guardar tiene 9 dígitos por lo tanto el programa no es capaz de guardarlo con tal precisión. Puedes solucionarlo utilizando `double` que normalmente es de [64 bits](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formato_en_coma_flotante_de_doble_precisi%C3%B3n).

Recuerda usar `scanf` así con `double`:

```
double d = 0;
scanf("%lf", &d);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono